# Trying to generate list based on map but unable to do so - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<ul className="nav nav-treeview">
  <li className="nav-item">
    <a href="#" className="nav-link">
      <i className="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
      <p>hi</p>
    </a>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Above snippet is giving me "hi"

```js
{
  [e].map((x, y) => {
    let arr = Object.keys(x).map(k => x[k]);

    arr[0].map((m, n) => {
      console.log("value from inner map", m.moduleName);
      return (
        <ul className="nav nav-treeview">
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a href="#" className="nav-link">
              <i className="far fa-circle nav-icon" />
              <p>hi</p>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      );
    });
  });
}
```

when I am console logging, I am getting the value from **m.moduleName**, however, I am not able to see the list that should have been generated.

```html
<ul className="nav nav-treeview">
  <li className="nav-item">
    <a href="#" className="nav-link">
      <i className="far fa-circle nav-icon" />
      <p>hi</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>;
```

When I run the same code again after my map, it is working fine too.

I want to generate the list based on the length of `arr[0]`. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Return the result of your inner mapping: `return arr[0].map((m, n ...`

Comment: @DacreDenny Is that an answer? If so, please put it in the answers, otherwise the question sits “unanswered” drawing in additional people to help.

Comment: @DacreDenny - I appreciate your prompt response, but if you elaborate your answer more that would really help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a return statement to the enclosing arrow function

```
{ [e].map((x, y) => {
    let arr = Object.keys(x).map(k => x[k]);

    return arr[0].map((m, n) => {
      console.log("value from inner map", m.moduleName);
      return (
        <ul className="nav nav-treeview">
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a href="#" className="nav-link">
              <i className="far fa-circle nav-icon" />
              <p>hi</p>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      );
    });
  });
}
```